# Weed Wacker Not Running Properly

Tags: carburetor, small-engine, two-stroke, lawnmower

I have a Remington weed wacker that is ~2 years old.  It worked great for the first 2 or 3 months but then I could not get it to work properly.  I have tried new gas, new plug, adjusting the idle on the carburetor and checking the screen in the carburetor and it still does not run properly.  It starts okay and will run somewhat decently on half choke but it stalls almost immediately after turning the choke off.  I have included a video hosted on my Google Drive account of it running (my 7 year old was the videographer so please forgive the jitters and finger in view lol)

Any thoughts on what it could be?

[Video of my weed wacker](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxJjaCFuo-5LQ0d6QUVhejk0Ulk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Usually this indicates to me the carb's main fuel ports are clogged (or nearly clogged) where it isn't passing enough fuel through and causing an extreme lean condition when it's running. The engine will run while on choke because there is enough vacuum to pull fuel through the semi-clogged ports.

Comment: To add on to the previous comment: Weed wacker carbs are generally so cheap that it's not worth trying to repair them. They are generally in the $10 - $15 range, so I'd probably just buy a new one instead of messing with it any more.

Comment: Is this the issue you are referring to? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg6iBd5MmgU

Comment: @cory - I've never had good luck at trying to rebuild them, either. Like you said, how cheap they are far outweighs the cost in time monkeying with them when ultimately you end up replacing it anyway.

Comment: Yep something is clogged a bit.  Every few years you have to remove the muffler and blow it out on 2 cycle engines.  The carbs are cheap on eBay but the lead time can be unbelievable long.  Get the carb ordered soon.

Comment: If your buying a new carb, make sure you have a tool to tune it.  I bought a new one and it was very far out of tune.